# How do I reference tables in the same schema as my function?

Tags: postgresql

I am creating a function within a schema that I am going to make a series of queries from. I want all of these queries to be made as if the schema of the function was first in the search path. I know I can change the search path within the context of the function, but I can't find how to learn the schema that my function is contained in from within my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to parse the `pg_context` return value of [`get diagnostics`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CALL-STACK):

```
create schema test_schema;

create or replace function test_schema.test_function()
returns text language plpgsql as $$
declare
    stack text;
begin
    get diagnostics stack = pg_context;
    return stack;
end $$;

select test_schema.test_function();

                              test_function                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PL/pgSQL function test_schema.test_function() line 5 at GET DIAGNOSTICS
(1 row)
```

If the function name is unique you can get the schema name querying the system catalog [`pg_namespace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/catalog-pg-namespace.html):

```
create or replace function test_schema.test_function_2()
returns text language sql as $$
    select nspname::text
    from pg_namespace n
    join pg_proc p on n.oid = pronamespace
    where proname = 'test_function_2'
$$;

select test_schema.test_function_2() as schema_name;

 schema_name 
-------------
 test_schema
(1 row)
```

Comment: I don't love the first solution; it seems to be very much a hack, which I guess just suggests that this isn't really something postgres is designed to do. The second is much neater but doesn't help me; I'm using the schemas in the first place to help deal with redundant names. I guess I'll just add the schema name as a text parameter whenever it would come up.

Comment: Different functions with the same name in multiple schemas is an antipattern, could cause strange troubles in the future.

Comment: this seems unreasonably vague. I'm using the similar named functions because they serve the same purpose in each schema, but may not have quite the same content. for instance, each of my schemas have an aggregate function that works over the same form of data, but how they weight aggregation may change from schema to schema. without more information on what 'strange troubles' are, how can I guess at a better way to accomplish such a thing?

Comment: Create one function (or maybe several overloaded functions) which conditionally perform different operations according to arguments.